# Duplicates must have at least one upvoted answer

Tags: support, duplicates

So, how come I can duplicate [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/818103/nvidia-drivers-on-asus-rog-gl522) with [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/814543/trouble-with-nvidia-drivers-on-asus-rog-gl522)?

Just curious really, is it because the same person asked the question?

Anyone know why?

FYI I can't just do it to any question

> [image]

So it is something about that one specifically.

Comment: I've been wondering if it's better to flag for mod attention in the case of a repost so thanks for asking

Comment: That is really incorrect! Indeed needs mod attention ^

Comment: AH, waitwait, I assume it is indeed because the posts have one and the same poster. I missed that. OP could have edited his first one if he assumed the verbosity was the reason. Would have brought it back to the front page as well.

Comment: @JacobVlijm IDK where your answer went? I assumed the same, it could well be a bug that triggers under a specific set of circumstances but it seems more likely, to me, this is some kind of overlooked intended behaviour, allowing us to close these type of post quickly.

Comment: Deleted it, since it was an assumption, undeleted it, since I am pretty sure it works like that :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because the system detects the post was marked as dupe of a post *by the same poster*.

He simply posted the same post again, in other wording. In such a case the post is a dupe, without a reason. Op simply could have edited his original question, if he came to the conclusion it was weakly worded or too long.

This also would have brought it back to the front page, giving the edited, more readable version a new chance.

Comment: I totally agree, this seems the most likely reason, I will vote up for now and a mod can confirm or deny.

Comment: Not many mods around at the moment it seems, so I tested this and yes, as long as the questions belong to the same user you can just duplicate them. Whoever you are?

Comment: yep, posts by the same user can always be marked as duplicates, because of dubble posting